# SignalR with msgpack hub protocol

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I used Flutter, SignalR to build a chat application.
I connected to socket server according to msgpack hub protocol. Unfortunately, the result that I get when using msgpack and json hub protocol is different.
I don't know my problem is in client or server connection library.
How to test msgpack hub protocol with postman or
something similar